# Dynamics web API - cannot group activities by activitytypecode

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am sending a request to the dynamics web API with the following parameters:

```
?$filter=_ownerid_value eq 'X'&$apply=groupby((activitytypecode),aggregate($count as count))
```

However I am getting the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AliasedValue' to type 'System.String'.

Could someone please help me construct a filter so that I can get the count of each activity type for the user?

Comment: There is a workaround by using fetchXml.
Your url should be like: xxxxxx?fetchXml=
<fetch aggregate="true">
  <entity name="activitypointer">
    <attribute name="activitytypecode" alias="typecode" groupby="true" />
    <attribute name="activityid" alias="id" aggregate="count" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="ownerid" operator="eq" value="XXXXX" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>